# Install different file for Windows 10 and Windows 7

Tags: wix

I have signed device drivers. The signature requirements are different for Windows 10 and Windows 7, therefore I have two sets of driver files.

I would like to using a single `.wxs` file and have the installer select filesets based on the version of Windows I am installing on. For simplicity, I am using `VersionNT >= 603` for Win 10 and `VersionNT < 603` for Win 7. I'm ignoring the fact that this doesn't take into account earlier versions of Windows or Server versions for now.

What I have done is create two Wix `<Components>`, each with unique names and GUIDs. Within the `<Component>` I have:

```
<!-- Pre-Win 10 -->
<difx:Driver AddRemovePrograms="no" DeleteFiles="yes" ForceInstall="no" Legacy="no" PlugAndPlayPrompt="no" /> 
<Condition><![CDATA[(VersionNT64 < 603)]]></Condition>
<File ....
```

or

```
<!-- Win 10 -->
<difx:Driver AddRemovePrograms="no" DeleteFiles="yes" ForceInstall="no" Legacy="no" PlugAndPlayPrompt="no" />
<Condition><![CDATA[(VersionNT64 >= 603)]]></Condition>
<File ....
```

Then I include `<ComponentRef>` for both components in a feature.

This compiles, but gives warnings for each `.sys`, `.cat`, and `.inf` of the form:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\src\Product\installer\Product.wxs(103,0): warning LGHT1076: ICE30: The target file 'driver.sys' might be installed in '[ProgramFiles64Folder]\Vendor\brbq3-yp\drivers\so-utx6z\' by two different conditionalized components on an SFN system: 'win10_driver' and 'win7_driver'. If the conditions are not mutually exclusive, this will break the component reference counting system.
```

In this case, I know the two conditions are mutually exclusive, but I'd like to clean up the warnings.

Can anyone recommend a cleaner way to install these mutually exclusive sets of driver files without creating two `.msi` packages?

Answer (score 7):

As your authoring accommodates the warning condition, you can suppress ICE30 to avoid the warning message in the build. Add a `SuppressIces` property to your .wixproj with value `ICE30`.

Comment: Thanks. That at least gets rid of the warnings. I still wonder if there's not a better way to write the code.